# Why the subtraction of two dates is different than the result from using DATEDIFF()?

Tags: mysql, sql

How does the two functions differ? Both columns are of date type.

The query I used is

```
SELECT 
     period_start,
     period_end,
     period_end - period_start AS subtract,
     DATEDIFF(period_start,period_end) AS datediff
FROM some table
```

| period_start | period_end | substract | datediff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 103 | 34 |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 103 | 34 |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 103 | 34 |
| 2018-12-01 | 2020-01-01 | 18900 | 396 |

Comment: the subtract  converts it into int so yoour first line is 228 -125, and the only correct way is to use the date functions

Comment: Thanks!!! Good to understand how it is handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`datediff()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_datediff.asp) and [`date_sub()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) are the only valid ways to perform a comparison between dates.

Subtracting two dates is not going to do what you expect. It will be converting the dates to a number and subtract the two numbers.

Credit to @nbk, on the integer math being performed on the dates:

| period_start | period_end | math | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 190228-190125 | 103 |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 190228-190125 | 103 |
| 2019-01-25 | 2019-02-28 | 190228-190125 | 103 |
| 2018-12-01 | 2020-01-01 | 200101-181201 | 18900 |